# How can i create a function given certain elements of its limits?

Tags: limits

Sorry if this is too elementary, I'm just a noob in calc1 atm...

Example: $f$ is not continuous at $x = 1$, but 
$\lim_{x\to 1^+} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x)$ exist and are equal.

I think that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)\neq  f(c)$ and I know that the limits from both side approach the same value. But what do I do knowing this? I'm having truoble visualizing functions with these properties(

Comment: Please verify the edit and learn MathJax. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

$$F(x)=\{\sin\frac{\pi}{2}x\}$$ 
where $\{x\}$ represents fractional part of $x$ .
i.e $\{1.4\}=.4$